# Difficulty in uninstalling older phonegap versions

Tags: xcode, cordova

How do i uninstall an already existing version of phonegap(1.3,1.8) because i want to install the new 2.0 and it does'nt get installed without uninstalling older versions. The folder structure of my older version 1.8 does'nt have uninstall option.

Any suggestions are welcome.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordova 2.0 onwards doesn't really have an 'installer' so you should be perfectly fine to leave your 1.3 if you like.

They only recommend uninstalling old versions if you are not going to use it so that the project template is removed from XCode. If you don't care about that you can leave the old version.

Just follow the upgrade steps from http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_upgrading_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Guides to start using 2.1 (which is now out and you should use)